# Adding new button dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to create a new button dynamically in javascript and using some jquery. This function doesn't work for some reason. It seems to falter at the append function. Any suggestions?

Here's the .js function

```
SwapButton: function(){
    var element = document.createElement('input');
    element.setAttribute("type", "button");
    element.setAttribute("value", "Trash Letters");
    element.setAttribute("onClick", "GB.swapLetters()");
    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].appendChild(element);
    $('input[type="button"]').append(element);
}
```

The html. The new button should be added to where the input types are

```
<body>
    <div class="hero-unit">

                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span8"></div>
                        <div id="timer" class="span4"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div id="score-board" class="span8"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid span12" id="word-area">

                    </div>

                    <div class="row-fluid" id="row1">
                        <div id="1" class="span2"></div>
                        <div id="2" class="span2"></div>
                        <div id="3" class="span2"></div>
                        <div id="4" class="span2"></div>
                        <div id="5" class="span2"></div>
                        <div id="6" class="span2"></div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row-fluid" id="row2">
                        <div id="7" class="span2"></div>
                        <div id="8" class="span2"></div>
                        <div id="9" class="span2"></div>
                        <div id="10" class="span2"></div>
                        <div id="11" class="span2"></div>
                        <div id="12" class="span2"></div>

                    </div>

                    <input type="button" onClick="GB.check()" value="Check"></input>
                    <input type="button" onClick="GB.clear()" value="Clear"></input>
                    <input type="button" onClick="GB.start()" value="Start"></input>

    </div>
```

Comment: `$('input[type="button"]').append(element);` would append an input in your buttons. That doesn't seem to make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) adds the new element as a **child element** if the element you're appending it to.

`<input>` elements cannot have children.

You may want to call [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/), which inserts the new element as a child of the element's parent, immediately after the element.

Comment: Won't this create 3 new buttons since I'm appending it to after 3 existing ones?

Comment: Yes it will create 3 instead of 1. Not the correct answer. Check out my answer.

Comment: @ono: Filter the object you're calling it on to only contain the element you want to insert after.

Answer (score 1):

you are appending the new button inside the other ones. try using the 'after()' method.

```
$('input[type="button"]').after(element);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `input` type `button` is not a container you may need [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)

```
 $(element).insertAfter('input[type="button"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the .after() with .last() method to append after the inputs so you don't duplicate. You can also use .append() to append to the hero unit.

Either

```
var $button = $('<input type="button">').val('Trash Letters').click(GB.swapLetters);
$('.hero-unit input[type="button"]').last().after($button);
```

or

```
$('.hero-unit').append($button);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery when you are using jQuery?

```
SwapButton: function(){
    $("<input />", {"type":"button","value":"Trash Letters"})
     .on("click",function() { GB.swapLetters() })
     .appendTo("#row2"); // for example
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add dom element in JQuery selector and this is not possibble with `.append()` function. You can create your element by using JQuery instead of `document.createElement..()` to append it;

```
var element =$('<input>',{type:'button',value:'Trash Letters'});
element.click(function(e){GB.swapLetters()})
elemend.appendTo(yourContainer)
```